# What is the position of the supreme deity's spouse in different Vaishnavite sects?

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, goddess, gaudiya-vaishnavism

Lakshmi,Sita and spouses of Krishna.  What is their position according to Srivaishnavites,Gaudiyas et al?  Are they also supreme or are they subservient to the supreme deity?

Comment: Even among srivaishnavites, there are two sects: thengalai and vadagalai. They have different views on the goddess.

Answer (score 1):

In Gaudiya Vaishnavisim Lakshmi is not a Jiva and is non different from Sri Vishnu.

In Madhava Sampradaya she is said to be a Jiva (hence subservient to Sri Vishnu).
But she and Durga are beyond Samsara.

There are two sects in Sri Vaishnavism - Vadakalai and Thenkalai. Vadakalaites do not consider as a Jiva(hence equal to Sri Vishnu)
But Thenkalites do say that she is a Jiva, but not an ordinary one as she is a Nitya Siddha. Hence she is subordinate to Vishnu but beyond Samsara etc.

Source: [Hari Das's answer in Quora](https://www.quora.com/Do-all-Vaishnav-Sampradays-consider-Laxmi-as-a-Jiva/answer/Hari-Das-435)

Answer (score 0):

If Supreme Lord is the all powerful (shaktimaan), His eternal consort is His internal potency (antaranga shakti). Without antaranga shakti, shaktimaan Lord is incomplete. Thus His eternal consort is not subservient, rather to be accepted as Their servant of the servants is the ultimate goal of our life.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).